# Converting from React-Router-dom v5 to v6 page contents not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having issues converting my code from meeting React-Router-Dom v5 requirements to V6 requirements. For some reason my webpage contents are not loading in the browser. Any help please? Ive tried doing the research and implementing different solutions but I havnt been able to fix the issue.

Here is my App.js
https://i.stack.imgur.com/USV67.png

Here is my index.js
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG96P.png

Comment: Issue was that <TopBar /> and <Single /> are not children of <Routes /> lol

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs some code, and answers shouldn't be posted in comments.

Comment: Please do edit your question to include the code as properly formatted and readable code snippets instead of as images of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Move `TopBar` out of the `Routes` component and move the `Single` component onto the route's `element` prop. The only valid children of the `Routes` component are the `React.Fragment` and `Route` components, and the only valid children of the `Route` component are other `Route` components.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const user = false;

  return (
    <>
      <TopBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/write" element={<Write />} />
        <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
        <Route path="/post/:postId" element={<Single />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```